# Algorithm to iterate TreeView nodes in reverese from the last leaf to root

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, algorithm, treeview

What is the best algorithm to iterate a WinForms TreeView control from the last leafs to roots in reverse? C#

Comment: Are you storing a reference to each node's position in the tree (i.e.: storing a reference to an ancestor node) within the node itself?

Comment: i think you're going to need to provide more detail. How is you're tree structured? does each node have a reference to it's parent? Are you starting at a specific node and need to travel directly to the root or traverse other nodes as well?

Comment: is structured the same as a WinForms TreeView control

Answer (score 6):

The code below will visit each node and traverse it completely, depth-first, until it comes to a leaf.  Then, as it unwinds the stack, will call `DoSomethingWithNode` for each node.  The `depth` parameter is there to show you that the nodes are returned in reverse order.

```
void ReverseTraverse(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int depth)
{
    if (nodes == null) return;
    foreach (TreeNode child in nodes)
    {
        ReverseTraverse(child.Nodes, depth+1);
        DoSomethingWithNode(child, depth);
    }
}
```

To call it, assuming that `MyTreeView` is a `TreeView` instance:

```
ReverseTraverse(MyTreeView.Nodes, 1);
```

Note that this doesn't give you the deepest leaf nodes first, but rather just makes sure that any leaf node is output before its parent node.  If your tree looks like this:

```
Node 1
  Node 1.1
  Node 1.2
    Node 1.2.1
Node 2
  Node 2.1
    Node 2.1.1
      Node 2.1.1.1
    Node 2.1.2
```

The output order will be:

```
Node 1.1
Node 1.2.1
Node 1.2
Node 1
Node 2.1.1.1
Node 2.1.1
Node 2.1.2
Node 2.1
Node 2
```

If you want the deepest nodes first (i.e. Node 2.1.1.1 would be output first), then you'd have to make a full traversal (in forward order would be easiest) and build a list of the nodes with their corresponding depths.  Then sort the list by depth (descending) and output in order.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but there are a couple of flaws in your code snippet - first you need to specify the type of `TreeNode` in your `foreach` since TreeNodeCollection is actually a collection of `object`.  Also, your recursive method call is using a different method name.  From a pseudo-code perspective it's great, it just doesn't build.  Also I think an empty check needs to occur on `.Nodes` so it doesn't try to dig further than it can.

Answer (score 0):

For a binary tree, you are looking for a reverse inorder traversal. To do that, you can push the nodes onto a linked list (through the right linked node) during an inorder traversal. Then you read the linked list backwards it backwards.

1. Convert the binary search tree to a doubly linked list using inorder traversal O(n).
2. Traverse that doubly linked list backwards. You can use two pointers for that.

Then you can have fun and optimize it :)

Comment: an inorder traversal will traverse the tree from left to right. post-order goes depth first.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a BT (Binary Tree), the best tree-walk to traverse the tree from the leafs to the root would be the Post-Order Tree-Walk. This visits the nodes in the following order: left -> right -> root. If you want to reverse this, use: right -> left -> root.

Pseudocode:

```
BottomUpTraversal(x)
    BottomUpTraversal(x.left)
    BottomUpTraversal(x.right)
    print(x.key)
```